# Project fails to build after downloading latest gradle version

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, apache-poi

Ever since the update, I keep getting the following error when I build. I have tried clean and build but the error persists:

This is the error I get when I try to build:

Error: Program type already present: org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.Location

The problem seems to be related to an issue with xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar, however I don't really understand what's it trying to do by "dexingTransform". Do I need to add anything to my gradle to support my project after the update?

This is my build.grade:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.testApp"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "org.apache.poi:poi:3.17"
    implementation "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.17"
    implementation 'com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

and the following reported errors that I cannot understand, which are coming up after the update:

```
 org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.   

Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.transform.ArtifactTransformException: Failed to transform file 'xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=26} using transform DexingTransform

Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.Location
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have figured out what the problem was. Turns out after updating to gradle 4.4, you'll get an error if you have duplicate library references in your project. In my case, this was xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar, and I had the following dependencies clashing with each other:

```
implementation "org.apache.poi:poi:3.17"
implementation "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.17"
implementation 'com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
```

So in my case I kept the following, and commented out the rest:

```
//implementation "org.apache.poi:poi:3.17"
//implementation "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.17"
//implementation 'com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
```

I then re-synced gradle, clean and build the project, and my issue was resolved.